# Cron Job error "Could not open input file"

Tags: cron

I've spent a solid day looking for a solution to this specific situation (on Stack Overflow and the Googs,) so I do apologize if this is already on Stack Overflow.

I'm trying to set up a fairly simple cron job in AWS via the command line:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /opt/app/current/record_user_login.php
```

The cron job successfully fires and is able to touch the file in question (it is hitting the correct environment.) However, I keep getting the error:

```
"Could not open input file"
```

I've:

- chmod'd the file to 777
- Changed the script to just echo "Hello world"
- Tried initiating the cronjob as the root user
- chmod'd the crontab file itself to 777

None of these solutions seem to work. For a yet unknown reason, I can't edit rsyslog.conf to turn on cronlog, so I don't have any data from that.

The contents of record_user_login are:

```
<?
    include("connect_to_mysql.php");

    //Logged in in 1 week
    $current_date = date('Y-m-j H:i:s', strtotime("-1 weeks"));

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM users_login_history WHERE sign_in_time > '$current_date'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $i++;
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO sqm_data (feature, action) VALUES ('user login', $i)";
    if(!mysql_query($query)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you've changed the script to echo "Hello World", does it actually print that out?

Comment: Nothing is printed, unfortunately. I just get the "Could not open input file" error

Comment: Whatever your problem is, ***chmod 777* is wrong and insecure!** Please do not perpetrate this antipattern.

Comment: Whoah. Cool down. At the time I had 0 clue what was happening so I was doing everything I could think of to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is absurdly late to the game, but I did find a solution to this. What was happening was:

I had originally typed up the cron commands in Windows Notepad and uploaded them. Apparently what was happening was a carriage return ("/r", IIRC) was getting plugged in, unbeknownst to me (and vim, when I viewed the file from putty.) A friend removed those carriage returns by a method I don't recall/did not follow too well unfortunately, but after the returns were removed, it all worked.

Comment: This exact thing happened to me today.  This obscure answer helped me a lot, one quick 'dos2unix' and it was running.  Thanks.

Comment: For god's sake - same simple thing. And I've even had this problem before with cron edit, but overlooked it.
FYI; you can convert/edit "linux format" files on windows with certain text editors, I use EditPad for this.  That can save it w/o the carriage returns.

Comment: i experience the same thing.. for some reason the file was getting saved in DOS format every time.

Comment: Had exact same trouble. To test for DOS CRLF line endings run file yourscript and if it returns 'ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators' you have wrong line endings.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I also edited cron file using Netbeans on Windows, and then wondered about 2 hours why my cron was not running, then finally edited the cron in Sublime Text on Ubuntu, and things started working

Comment: I wish I had found this sooner. This caused me at least a day of work. Nice fix!

Comment: at the risk of sounding stupid, what is the answer? I mean actual reason and way-out?

Comment: Man I wish I knew; if someone else has visibility into looking behind the curtain on documents (sounds like folks have had success here), that would be awesome. I'm sorry I can't be of more help!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/cron/; /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron/filename.php -q -f
```

Comment: When an answer has a green check to the left of it, this answer was accepted as the solution. No need to answer unless you can add a new of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /opt/app/current/record_user_login.php
```

Try adding the -q flag. Also, it might be beneficial if you're not already, to log your output.

Are you sure your path to PHP is correct? I've seen examples that simply do this:

```
* * * * * php -q /opt/app/current/record_user_login.php
```

You may want to give that a try.

Comment: Thanks for following up. Unfortunately, I still get the error when I add the -q flag. As for logging the output, I can't seem to edit the .conf file to turn on cronlog (yet another issue I'm having.)

Comment: Do you have full access to the server in order to edit the conf file? If you're on shared hosting this file is likely not accessible to you.

Comment: Finally got this to work. Here's what I'm getting in the log. Don't see anything in particular: "Jul 14 19:58:01 ip-10-212-147-129 CROND[14473]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php /opt/app/current/Scripts/record_user_logins.php^M)
Jul 14 19:58:01 ip-10-212-147-129 CROND[14473]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php /opt/app/current/Scripts/record_user_logins.php^M)"

Comment: Thanks for keeping up with this, I realize it must be a little frustrating with my not having found a solution yet. The path I provided for the php file is correct; I tried a couple other paths which where listened on a whereis result (such as /usr/lib/php, which is a directory), but none of them worked.

Comment: Are you able to post the contents of record_user_login.php?

Comment: I've added the contents of the file in my original question. I do get the same error when I replace the contents with just <? echo ("Hello world"); ?>

Comment: What do you get when you execute the following command: ls -l /opt/app/current/record_user_login.php

Comment: "From: root@ip-10-212-147-129.ec2.internal (Cron Daemon)
To: ec2-user@ip-10-212-147-129.ec2.internal
Subject: Cron <ec2-user@ip-10-212-147-129> /usr/bin/php ls -l /opt/app/current/Scripts/record_user_logins.php
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/ec2-user>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=ec2-user>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=ec2-user>

Could not open input file: ls"

Comment: In the cronlog: "Jul 15 19:06:01 ip-10-212-147-129 CROND[3557]: (ec2-user) CMD (/usr/bin/php ls -l /opt/app/current/Scripts/record_user_logins.php^M)
Jul 15 19:06:01 ip-10-212-147-129 CROND[3557]: (ec2-user) CMD (/usr/bin/php ls -l /opt/app/current/Scripts/record_user_logins.php^M)"

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - don't use that as cron script arguments, but just go into the command line, and type that command. If it can't find the file, then it will tell you.

Comment: It looks like it's able to find the file: "-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user 527 Jul 12 19:14 /opt/app/current/Scripts/record_user_logins.php"

Comment: Your original notes the file path as /opt/app/current/record_user_login.php, but in the last comment it says /opt/app/current/Scripts/record_user_logins.php. You're missing "Scripts" in the first one. Is that it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here. I changed the directory of the file a while back (on the server and on the cron job); that isn't the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

In cpanel this one solve my problem

```
 php -q -f /home/skat_2347/public_html/cron.php /home/skat_2347/public_html/
```